# Visual inconsistency when getting new reputation on the user profile

Tags: bug, status-bydesign, reputation, profile-page

I was surprised to see on [one of my SE profiles](https://health.stackexchange.com/users/43/franck-dernoncourt?tab=reputation):

[image]

I got a `-2` according to the tab header, but no `-2` was visible in the reputation details. It took around one minute before it finally got displayed:

[image]

Comment: Did you try to blame caching?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The reputation history is still cached like everything else on the site. If no other events have occurred for the current day, then it can take a short bit of time for the current date to actually appear in the list. Once the day does appear, though, any further events for the day should appear immediately.